# How can I perform an SQl where query then list properly?

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, where-clause

I am trying to perform the following:

```
def query = Scholarship.withCriteria {
  eq('activeInd', "A")
}
allInfo = query.list(sort: "name", order: "asc")

return allInfo
}
```

I was previously using this, but now I need to change it to something like above:

```
def allInfo = Scholarship.list(sort: "name", order: "asc")
```

I need to get all scholarship objects with activeInd field = A. Then I need to use .list on them to get all those scholarships in a list/array in ascending order based off the name. The error I am running into is as follows:

No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: last(), last(), first(), first(), is(java.lang.Object), toList()

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `list()` on the result of `withCriteria`. This can resolved by either of the three ways:

```
def result = Scholarship.createCriteria().list(sort: 'name', order: 'asc') {
    eq('activeInd', "A")

    //alternatively
    //order('name', 'asc')
}
```

or

```
def result = Scholarship.withCriteria {
    eq('activeInd', "A")
    order('name', 'asc')
}
```

or

```
def result = Scholarship.where {
    activeInd == 'A'
}.list(sort: 'name', order: 'asc')
```

I would prefer the third approach using *where*.